# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+a+a^2+\dots+a^n}{1+b+b^2+\dots+b^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm fairly confident I got the right idea, but I'm not quite sure how to state the answer...

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+a+a^2+\dots+a^n}{1+b+b^2+\dots+b^n}&=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+a+a^2+\dots+a^n}{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+b+b^2+\dots+b^n}\\
&=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-b^{n+1}}{1-b}}\\
&=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-a^{n+1})(1-b)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-a)(1-b^{n+1})}\\
&=\begin{cases}\frac{1-b}{1-a}&&\text{if } |a|,|b|<1\\\infty&&\text{if }|a|>1,|b|<1\\0&&\text{if }|a|<1,|b|>1\\
DNE&&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align}
I'm not confident on the DNE part, and I don't know if there are other cases I'm missing. Also, fwiw, this is for a real analysis class, where the assignment says "**You need to show your calculation, but no need to use '$\epsilon-N$' language to prove.**"

Comment: Well, $|a|=1$ implies $a=1$ or $a=-1$. So your last case splits in 4 cases.

Comment: What if it evaluates to $\infty/\infty$? I was always told that this is not definitive, and might require L'Hopital's rule... It may converge and may not.

Comment: If it evaluates to ${\infty \over \infty}$ use l'Hopital on ${1 - a^{n+1} \over 1- b^{n+1}}$. Also you have to consider the case where $|a| = 1$ or $|b|=1$.

Comment: If $a=b=1$ then obviously the limit is 1.

Comment: l'Hospital cannot be used for multivariable formula in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\ge b> 1$,

$\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-a^{n+1})(1-b)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-a)(1-b^{n+1})}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-b}{1-a}\frac{b^{-(n+1)}-(a/b)^{(n+1)}}{b^{-(n+1)}-1}=\infty$

Since 
$|\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+a+a^2+\dots+a^n}{\lim_{n\to\infty}1-b+b^2+\dots+(-1)^nb^n}|\ge|\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+a+a^2+\dots+a^n}{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+b+b^2+\dots+b^n}|$,

if $a\ge  -b>1$,

$\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+a+a^2+\dots+a^n}{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+b+b^2+\dots+b^n}=\infty$

If $b\ge a> 1$,

$\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-a^{n+1})(1-b)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-a)(1-b^{n+1})}=0$

Since 
$|\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}1-a+a^2+\dots+(-1)^na^n}{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+b+b^2+\dots+b^n}|\le|\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+a+a^2+\dots+a^n}{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+b+b^2+\dots+b^n}|$,

if $b\ge -a>1$,

$\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+a+a^2+\dots+a^n}{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+b+b^2+\dots+b^n}=0$

Not sure about other cases.