# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+n^2+n^3+...+n^n}{1^n+2^n+3^n+...+n^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-integration

Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+n^2+n^3+....+n^n}{1^n+2^n+3^n+....+n^n}$$

**My Attempt**

Was able to write as $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{n^n-1}{n-1}}{n^n(\frac{1}{n})\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^n}$$

But not sure how to take it further though the denominator appears to be Riemann Sum

Comment: Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792441/evaluate-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-fracnn2n3-cdots-nn1n2n) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527668/calculate-lim-n-to-infty-frac1aa2-dotsan1bb2-dotsbn)